# Ask pattern not working using akka streams

Tags: scala, akka, akka-stream

I try to implement a sample slightly different from the [tutorial](https://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/2.5/stream/stream-integrations.html#integrating-with-actors):

```
object Test extends App {
      class A extends Actor {
        override def receive: Receive = {
          case 10 => context.system.terminate()
          case x =>
            println(s"Received: $x")
            sender() ! x
        }
      }

      implicit val system = ActorSystem()
      implicit val materializer = ActorMaterializer()
      implicit val dispatcher = system.dispatcher
      implicit val askTimeout = Timeout(1, TimeUnit.SECONDS)

      val a = system.actorOf(Props[A])

      val graph = RunnableGraph.fromGraph(GraphDSL.create() {
        {
          implicit builder: GraphDSL.Builder[NotUsed] => {
            import GraphDSL.Implicits._

            val source: Source[Int, NotUsed] = Source(1 to 10)
            source ~> Flow[Int].ask(2)(a) ~> Sink.foreach[String](println)
            ClosedShape
          }
        }
      })

      val x = graph.run()
}
```

In result i get this:

> Received: 1
>
> Received: 2

But i expect this:

> Received: 1
>
> 1
>
> Received: 2
>
> 2
>
> ...
>
> Received: 9
>
> 9

If i send messages to actor via `Source.actorRef` then all is ok and actor receive all messages. It seems like materialized actor wait a response from referenced actor.
How to fix it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you replace the `Sink.foreach[String](println)` with `Sink.onComplete(println)`
you will see that the flow terminates with an error:

```
Received: 1
Received: 2
Failure(java.lang.ClassCastException: Cannot cast java.lang.Integer to scala.runtime.Nothing$)
```

The problem is that Source.ask needs to know what class to map the actor's reply to [see API docs](https://doc.akka.io/api/akka/current/akka/stream/scaladsl/Source.html#ask[S](parallelism:Int)(ref:akka.actor.ActorRef)(implicittimeout:akka.util.Timeout,implicittag:scala.reflect.ClassTag[S]):FlowOps.this.Repr[S]). Otherwise it will try to cast the reply to Nothing and internally throw an exception.

To fix your original code replace ask with ask[Int]:

```
  val graph = RunnableGraph.fromGraph(GraphDSL.create() {
    {
      implicit builder: GraphDSL.Builder[NotUsed] => {
        import GraphDSL.Implicits._

        val source: Source[Int, NotUsed] = Source(1 to 10)
        source ~> Flow[Int].ask[Int](2)(a) ~> Sink.foreach(println)
        ClosedShape
      }
    }
  })
```